# Error in Ordered Probit with Simulated Maximum Likelihood in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, simulation, maximize

I am 'trying' to program a ordered probit model with random effects with simulated maximum likelihood in R.

I have adapted a code by Chris Adolph (http://faculty.washington.edu/cadolph/?page=21)

```
set.seed(10234)
nobs <- 1000

x1 <- rnorm(nobs)*.15^.5
x2 <- rnorm(nobs)*.35^.5
z <- rnorm(nobs)*.25^.5
y <- round(runif(nobs, 1,5), 0)
x <- cbind(x1, x2)

#### Generate Halton Sequences
library("randtoolbox")
R <- 200
#a <- matrix(999, nrow=R, ncol=nobs)
a <- halton(n=nobs, dim=R, normal=T, init=T)

# Likelihood for 5 category ordered probit
llk.oprobit5 <- function(param, x, y) {
    # preliminaries
    x <- as.matrix(x)
    os <- rep(1, nrow(x))
    x <- cbind(os, x)
    b <- param[1:ncol(x)]
    t2 <- param[(ncol(x)+1)]
    t3 <- param[(ncol(x)+2)]
    t4 <- param[(ncol(x)+3)]
    sigma_a <- param[ncol(x)+4]

    # probabilities and penalty function
    xb <- x %*% b %*% rep(1, R)
    asigma <- a * sigma_a

    p1 <- pnorm(- xb - asigma)
    if (t2 <= 0) {
        p2 <- -(abs(t2) * 10000)    # penalty function to keep t2>0
    } else {
        p2 <- pnorm(t2 - xb - asigma) - pnorm(- xb - asigma)
    }
    if (t3 <= t2) {
        p3 <- -((t2-t3)*10000)    # penalty to keep t3>t2
    } else {
        p3 <- pnorm(t3 - xb - asigma) - pnorm(t2 - xb - asigma)
    }
    if (t4 <= t3) {
        p4 <- -((t3 - t4) * 10000)
    } else {
        p4 <- pnorm(t4 - xb - asigma) - pnorm(t3 - xb - asigma) 
    }
    p5 <- 1 - pnorm(t4 - xb - asigma)

    p1 <- log(apply(p1, MARGIN=1, FUN=sum)/R)
    p2 <- log(apply(p2, MARGIN=1, FUN=sum)/R)
    p3 <- log(apply(p3, MARGIN=1, FUN=sum)/R)
    p4 <- log(apply(p4, MARGIN=1, FUN=sum)/R)
    p5 <- log(apply(p5, MARGIN=1, FUN=sum)/R)

    # -1 * log likelihood (optim is a minimizer)
    -sum(cbind(y==1, y==2, y==3, y==4, y==5) * cbind(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5))
}

# Use optim directly
ls.result <- lm(y~x)                    # use ls estimates as starting   values
stval <- c(ls.result$coefficients,1,2,3,2)  # initial guesses
oprobit.result <- optim(stval, llk.oprobit5, method="BFGS", x=x, y=y, hessian = T)
```

However, the code gave me the following error: 
    Error in apply(p3, MARGIN = 1, FUN = sum) : 
        dim(X) must have a positive length
    Called from: apply(p3, MARGIN = 1, FUN = sum)

I already used the debug() function and I am able to run all functions separately and I can print the values in each step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the averaging over the Halton sequences that you are doing needs to be performed only if the respective parameter values are in the allowed ranges. Note that I moved the lines `log(apply(…))` inside each respective `if` branch:

```
set.seed(10234)
nobs <- 1000

x1 <- rnorm(nobs)*.15^.5
x2 <- rnorm(nobs)*.35^.5
z <- rnorm(nobs)*.25^.5
y <- round(runif(nobs, 1,5), 0)
x <- cbind(x1, x2)

#### Generate Halton Sequences
library("randtoolbox")
R <- 200
a <- halton(n=nobs, dim=R, normal=T, init=T)

# Likelihood for 5 category ordered probit
llk.oprobit5 <- function(param, x, y) {
    # preliminaries
    x <- as.matrix(x)
    os <- rep(1, nrow(x))
    x <- cbind(os, x)
    b <- param[1:ncol(x)]
    t2 <- param[(ncol(x)+1)]
    t3 <- param[(ncol(x)+2)]
    t4 <- param[(ncol(x)+3)]
    sigma_a <- param[ncol(x)+4]

    # probabilities and penalty function
    xb <- x %*% b %*% rep(1, R)
    asigma <- a*sigma_a

    p1 <- pnorm(-xb-asigma)
    p1 <- log(apply(p1, MARGIN=1, FUN=sum)/R)

    if (t2 <= 0) {
        p2 <- -(abs(t2) * 10000)    # penalty function to keep t2>0
    } else {
        p2 <- pnorm(t2-xb-asigma)-pnorm(-xb-asigma)
        p2 <- log(apply(p2, MARGIN=1, FUN=sum)/R)
    }
    if (t3 <= t2) {
        p3 <- -((t2-t3)*10000)    # penalty to keep t3>t2
    } else {
        p3 <- pnorm(t3-xb-asigma)-pnorm(t2-xb-asigma)   
        p3 <- log(apply(p3, MARGIN=1, FUN=sum)/R)
    }
    if (t4 <= t3) {
        p4 <- -((t3-t4)*10000)
    } else {
        p4 <- pnorm(t4-xb-asigma)-pnorm(t3-xb-asigma) 
        p4 <- log(apply(p4, MARGIN=1, FUN=sum)/R)
    }
    p5 <- 1 - pnorm(t4-xb-asigma)
    p5 <- log(apply(p5, MARGIN=1, FUN=sum)/R)

    # -1 * log likelihood (optim is a minimizer)
    -sum(cbind(y==1,y==2,y==3,y==4, y==5) * cbind(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5))
}

# Use optim directly
ls.result <- lm(y~x)                    # use ls estimates as starting   values
stval <- c(ls.result$coefficients,1,2,3,2)  # initial guesses

oprobit.result <- optim(stval, llk.oprobit5, method="BFGS", x=x, y=y, hessian=T, control = list(trace = 10, REPORT = 1))
```

which then runs successfully:

```
...
iter  20 value 1567.966484
iter  21 value 1567.966434
iter  22 value 1567.966389
iter  23 value 1567.966350
iter  23 value 1567.966349
iter  23 value 1567.966345
final  value 1567.966345 
converged
```

producing the results:

```
pe <- oprobit.result$par                # point estimates
vc <- solve(oprobit.result$hessian)     # var-cov matrix
se <- sqrt(diag(vc))                    # standard errors
ll <- -oprobit.result$value             # likelihood at maximum

> pe
(Intercept)         xx1         xx2                                                 
 1.14039048 -0.05864677  0.04268965  0.77838577  1.43517145  2.23191376  0.02237956 
> vc
 (Intercept)           xx1           xx2                                                        
 (Intercept)  2.704159e-03 -7.945238e-05  4.507541e-07  1.520451e-03  1.970613e-03  2.215032e-03  9.274348e-04
 xx1         -7.945238e-05  7.300705e-03  1.165960e-04 -9.066118e-06 -6.078438e-05 -1.046191e-04 -2.009612e-04
 xx2          4.507541e-07  1.165960e-04  2.850668e-03  3.795273e-05  3.951004e-05  3.506606e-05 -2.686577e-04
1.520451e-03 -9.066118e-06  3.795273e-05  2.107875e-03  1.860727e-03  1.728905e-03  9.524469e-05
1.970613e-03 -6.078438e-05  3.951004e-05  1.860727e-03  2.955453e-03  2.576940e-03  1.960465e-04
2.215032e-03 -1.046191e-04  3.506606e-05  1.728905e-03  2.576940e-03  4.262996e-03  2.723117e-04
9.274348e-04 -2.009612e-04 -2.686577e-04  9.524469e-05  1.960465e-04  2.723117e-04  5.636931e-03
> se
(Intercept)         xx1         xx2                                                 
 0.05200153  0.08544417  0.05339165  0.04591160  0.05436408  0.06529162  0.07507950 
> ll
[1] -1567.966
```

Comment: That helped a lot! Thank you!